# How to read XML file using FileReader javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, xml-parsing, filereader, webodf

I need to get XML from a ODF file. I tried using FileReader readAsText and readAsBinaryString but its not working.

**FileReader readAsText** returns some special characters for odf files.

with **readAsBinaryString**

```
var reader = new FileReader()

reader.onloadend=function(e){

    var data = e.target.result;
    //data is not in xml format
    var xml = str2xml(data);
    //getting error
    /*
     using DOM parser for xml parsing
    */
}

reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
```

How can get XML from ODF file using javascript FileReader?

Comment: Try read as binary and then parse the content for the xml

Answer (score 6):

Here's a browser-based example, but this should be applicable to other JavaScript contexts:

**Make a Form:**

```
<div id="upload">
    <h2>Gimme Yo ODF Cornbread</h2>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <input type="file" name="odfxml" id="odfxml" />
    </form>
</div>
```

**Handle the Upload:** (I'm using JQuery for brevity/simplicity)

```
<script>
    $("#odfxml").change(function(){
        var file = document.getElementById("odfxml").files[0];
                    //You could insert a check here to ensure proper file type
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsText(file);
        reader.onloadend = function(){
            var xmlData = $(reader.result);
        };
    });
</script>
```

The `xmldata` variable contains your XML, ready for your magic.

Answer (score 2):

Using the response like text:

```
var xml = data.replace(/[\s\S]+<\?xml/, '<?xml');
xml = xml.replace(/office:document\-meta>[\s\S]+/, 'office:document-meta>');
```

:)

If you need to load the xml like jquery object:

```
xml = $(xml);
```

then you can use jquery selector's on