# Angular 8: Read text from XML file

Tags: xml, angular

Upon selecting an XML file with an open file dialog I want to read the contents of this file into some variable as a string.

I found here the following code. 
How can I return "theBytes" from processFile ?

Thank you in advance,
Zvika

```
    public processFile(theFile)
```

{

```
return function(e) 
{ 
    var theBytes = e.target.result; 
    console.log (theBytes); 
}
```

}

```
var f = event.files[0];
let fileReader = new FileReader();
fileReader.onload = this.processFile(f);
fileReader.readAsText(f);
```

Comment: You can check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20853219/how-to-read-xml-file-using-filereader-javascript

Comment: Data read from file should be handled only inside: return function (e). Am I right ?

Comment: Yes from the event.

Comment: try `fileReader.onload = this.processFile`

Answer (score 0):

the onload callback needs to be assigned to a callback function you are executing the function and assigning the response of processFile.

You need to assign the callback like this

```
fileReader.onload = this.processFile
```